# TideSDK - postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, tidesdk

is there a way to connect to a postgreSQL Database? I've noticed that the PHP module doesn't have the postgres extensions and its not possible to load it dynamically.

Is there any other way? An external PHP scripts will be the worst solution.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with Tide, but reviewing their docs here are the places I would look:

1. Javascript-> PostgreSQL [Is there a possibility of connecting postgreSQL directly to Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029358/is-there-a-possibility-of-connecting-postgresql-directly-to-javascript)
2. Python -> PostgreSQL, like psychopg.
3. If that fails, along with other similar languages, MAY be able to find another driver written fully in a language like this.
4. The PostgreSQL protocol is extensively documented and several implementations exist for it.  You could probably adapt either the Javascript driver or implement in another language to give you a direct driver to PostgreSQL http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/protocol-flow.html